# How to make a CakePHP3 login with username only

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

So i wanted to do a very basic authentication , and by following the Blog tutorial on https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html i tried to make it only use Username to log in, but the login system doesn't work because

```
$user = $this->Auth->identify();
```

Always returns false, I have searched cake's documentation on Authentication but can't find anything to help me.
Can someone tell me how do to make a costum login authentication.

Current login action:

```
  public function login()
  {
      if ($this->request->is('post')) {
          $user = $this->Auth->identify();
          if ($user) {
              $this->Auth->setUser($user);
              return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
          }
          $this->Flash->error(__('Invalid username, try again'));
      }
  }
```

And its View:

```
<div class="users form">
<?= $this->Flash->render() ?>
<?= $this->Form->create() ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?= __('Please enter your username') ?></legend>
        <?= $this->Form->control('username') ?>
    </fieldset>
<?= $this->Form->button(__('Login')); ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
</div>
```

AuthComponent Init:

```
  public function initialize(array $config)
{
    $controller = $this->_registry->getController();
    $this->eventManager($controller->eventManager());
    $this->response =& $controller->response;
    $this->session = $controller->request->session();
}
```

Comment: You could look into manually logging the users in. You could do so by checking if the username exists and if so manually logging them in by getting the user information and using the setUser() method. https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#manually-logging-users-in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few trial and error I managed to make my own login with username only that gets all usernames from a column in Database and stores them in an Iterator with

```
$usernames = $this->UsersTable->find()->extract('username');
```

and then I convert to an array of strings with

```
$usernamesArray= iterator_to_array($usernames);
```

I check if the requested data is Post and I do a loop to check all usernames, after that i trim both the input which is $user and the $usernameArray to ensure they are equal and if it is I authenticate my user and redirect him to my main page again.

```
$usernames = $this->Table->find()->extract('username');
    $usernamesArray= iterator_to_array($usernames);
    $user = $this->request->getData('username');
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        for($i = 0 ; $i < count($usernamesArray) ; $i++ ){
          if(trim($user) == trim($usernamesArray[$i])){
            $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            $this->Auth->setUser($user);
            return;
          }
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, CakePHP doesn't have a method of logging in a user by just the username. I'm providing an example of what the could could/would look like. This is off the top of my head and in no way tested.

```
   public function login() {
        if($this->request->is(['post'])) {
            if ($this->Users->exists(['username' => $this->request->getData('username')])) {
                $user = $this->Users->findByUsername($this->request->getData('username'))->first()->toArray();
                $this->Auth->setUser($user);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I will look into it after lunch.

Comment: Doesn't work , still give me error when i try to acess a non authorized page. If you could revise the code it would be appreciated.

Comment: I'd test the `$user` value instead of using an `exists()`, but generally manually logging a user in via `setUser()` like this works just fine. So, @DanielPereira you should do some debugging to figure out why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: I've edited this to make it work, this works but it's sloppy. @ndm method may be better, as it only makes one call to the database.